# Social buttons move up (jquery?)

Tags: jquery, move

How is it possible to create a script that works like this [here](http://www.tvinformatie.com/)?
You hover on the social buttons and then they move up a little bit..

Comment: All I can see from your link is that *Apache is functioning normally*. Very informative indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this with jQuery: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any social buttons in your link (maybe i am just blind ;)) but if you want to move up something after hovering it, you can do it with pure CSS

```
.arrow
{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.arrow i
{
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.arrow:hover
{
  background-color: blue;
}
.arrow:hover i
{
  top: 5px;
}
```

Here you have example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1fa023s/)